# How to inherit from the windows explorer (in any programming language, with help of any tool)

Tags: windows, desktop, explorer, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

How to inherit from the windows explorer (Desktop, thing with help of which we explore our Mu computer and so on directory’s) (in any programming language)?

- customize it
- add program fetchers ( adding to Windows Explorer Mac teachers or sorting algorithms or adding buttons or anything )

---

**What do I need:**

1. EXAMPLES
2. Open Source libs and Open Source Examples
3. Docs (for ex MSDN or something like this)

---

PS: It should work on\with Windows Vista, 7

Comment: What do you mean by fetchers? What do you want to customize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a wide range of things that would be implemented in a bunch of different ways.  The general rubric for this whole family of stuff is "shell extensions" and the [Windows Shell documentation in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a reasonable starting point (not great, but reasonable).  It includes a number of [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940376%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The terminology you find in the MSDN docs should also prove a good starting point for searching for more specific examples e.g. on CodeProject or for asking more specific questions on Stack Overflow.